# my these two programs are looking same but one of these is causing error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

here are my two programs and have a small difference. the first program compiles without error but the second program is giving error
[enter image description here][1]

***Program 1:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[][4] = { 5,7,5,9,4,6,3,1,2,9,0,6 };

    int *p;
    int(*q)[4];
    p = (int*)a;
    q = a;
    printf("%u %u\n", p, q);
    p++;
    q++;
    printf("%u %u\n", p, q);
    return 0;
}
```

this program compiles without any errors

***Program 2:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[][4]={5,7,5,9,4,6,3,1,2,9,0,6};

    int *p;
    int *q[4];
    p=(int*)a;
    q=a;

    printf("%u %u\n",p,q);

    p++;
    q++;

    printf("%u %u\n",p,q);
    return 0;
}
```

program 2 shows error in the line 8 and 13
WHY?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers!

Comment: `int *q[4];` --> array of `int *`s, `int (*q)[4];` pointer to an array.

Comment: That said, use `%p` for printing pointers.

Comment: @Hash it is array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the programs are `int (*q)[4];` versus `int *q[4];`

So let's see what https://cdecl.org/ says about the types.

> First code example
>
> int (*q)[4];
>
> declare q **as pointer** to array 4 of int

So here `q` is a pointer and therefore you can assign to it - like `q=a;`

> Second code example
>
> int *q[4];
>
> declare q **as array** 4 of pointer to int

So here `q` is an array and therefore you can **not** assign to it, i.e. `q=a;` is illegal.

For the second code example gcc gives the error:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
     q=a;
      ^
```

which actually says the same, i.e. that you are assigning to something being an array (and that is an error, i.e. illegal).

Comment: ThankQ for your answer it helped me alot. your answer is short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is because arrays are not assignable. `q` in the second program is defined as an array of pointers, so when you do: `q = a;`, this is not valid in C. Likewise, when you write `q++`, this is equivalent to `q = q + 1;`, so same kind of error.